# numeric_if validator in Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel

I have a custom request that works like this:

```
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
       'adminFee' => "required_if:useAdminFee,1",
```

...but I need something like:

```
  'adminFee' => "required_if:useAdminFee,1|numeric_if:useAdminFee,1"
```

It looks like this doesn't exist out of the box? If that's the case, what's the fastest way for me to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Conditionally adding rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).
In your case just override `getValidatorInstance` method in FormRequest class like so:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $v = parent::getValidatorInstance();
    $v->sometimes('adminFee', 'required|numeric', function($input) {
        return $input->useAdminFee == 1;
    });
    return $v;
}
```

and remove validation rule for `adminFee` from `rules` method

Comment: is there a way to do the same inside of rules of a custom request, or is that not possible?

Comment: What file did you modify? You've needed to modify your request class that extends `FormRequest`. Did this solution work?